# Unable know the exception in query

Tags: sql-server

I'm writing the below query in SQL Server

```
update time_tracker 
set logout = GETDATE(), 
    totaltime = SUBSTRING(CONVERT(varchar(20), (LOGOUT - LOGIN),120),12,8) from Time_Tracker 
where userid = 0138039
  and CONVERT(Date, LOGIN) = CONVERT(Date, GETDATE());
```

Basically, when the user hits a logout button I'm trying to achieve the below.

1. Enter the logout datetime stamp in my logout column
2. Calculate the difference between the login and logout time and update the total time column, bu checking for today's date and the current user.

When I do this, I'm getting this exception:

> Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Line 1
>   Error converting data type varchar to float.

Please let me know where I'm going wrong and how can I fix this.

Also when I run the below query

```
Select 
    SUBSTRING(CONVERT(varchar(20), (LOGOUT - LOGIN),120),12,8) 
from 
    Time_Tracker;
```

It is working fine, I mean I'm getting the correct time output.

Thanks

Comment: What is the datatype of `totaltime` ?

Comment: Hi @Arulkumar, it is float

Comment: Better use `DATEDIFF` instead of  `LOGOUT - LOGIN`, it will give you an integer value. Why `totaltime` is float?

Comment: Never mind that float is the wrong time to use for storing time or date data - why all these string manipulations if the type is float?? Why don't you write `totaltime=LOGOUT - LOGIN` ? Do the fields use some weird format to represent times? Of course, if you used `datetime` for both columns, you wouldn't need any conversion - a simple `DATEDIFF` would do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to get `hh:mm:ss` from `LOGOUT - LOGIN` based on `12,8` in `SUBSTRING` function. And put them into float column.

I think it is better to store differences in integer datatype in milliseconds. Or use time datatype for that column.

Try to use [DATEDIFF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx):

```
Select DATEDIFF(ms,LOGIN,LOGOUT) from Time_Tracker;
```

That will give you the time between two dates in milliseconds.

Or ALTER your column to `time` format.