# A tricky query to update the table with values of another table

Tags: sql-server

This question is an extension of my previous one available at [Unable know the exception in query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38827537/unable-know-the-exception-in-query#38827537).

This time I've Another table named breaks.

And it looks like below.

[image]

I'm able to get the column sum using the below query.

```
SELECT DATEADD(SECOND, SUM(DATEDIFF(SECOND, '19000101', TotalBreakTime)), '19000101') where 
where USERID = 0138039 AND CONVERT(Date, StartTime) = CONVERT(Date, GETDATE()))
as t FROM BreaksTable;
```

My second table looks like below.

[image]

This time, I want to update the breaks column with the sum of the `totalbreaktime` from Breaks table(the first screenshot) and the condition has to be the date is to be current day.

I'm really unable to understand how to do this.

Comment: I'm using sql server

Comment: What is the datatype of `Breaks` column ?

Comment: Hi @KrishnrajRana, I need the sum of only `TotalBreakTime` it is of `datetime`

Comment: @user3872094 And? We could already see that from your tag. And it supports `MERGE` very well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need [MERGE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx):

```
MERGE SecondTable as target
USING (
    SELECT  USERID, 
            SUM(DATEDIFF(SECOND, '19000101', TotalBreakTime)) as ColumnWithBreaksCount 
    FROM BreaksTable
    where CONVERT(Date, StartTime) = CONVERT(Date, GETDATE()))
    GROUP BY USERID) as source
ON target.USERID = source.USERID
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE
    SET BREAKS = source.ColumnWithBreaksCount
```

But this will work only if you have only one column for each `USERID` in your secondtable, else you need to add another key kolumn in `ON` part of query, which will help to make rows unique.

Comment: Hi gofr1 whats `--your query` here?

Comment: @user3872094 query which give `USERID` and `Breaks` sum. F.e. `SELECT USERID, SUM(Breaks) as ColumnWithBreaksCount FROM FirstTable GROUP BY USERID`

Comment: Add query from your sample, which counts sum for all userid's

Comment: He this is working fine, But Can I make this into a int?

Comment: Nice! `SUM(DATEDIFF(SECOND, '19000101', TotalBreakTime))` this is already `integer`. Then you for some reason use `dateadd`, I dont know why. Maybe remove this part from second column an left only `SUM(DATEDIFF(SECOND, '19000101', TotalBreakTime))`?

Comment: You are genious man, This worked absolutely Fantastic... Thanks a lot ;)